# Anyway to alter input to show only last 4 digits but only if not hovered?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input

For example, if I input `123456789` and leave focus the input will change to `*****6789`

I have a working example but I am unsure if this is without potential bugs. Is there a better way?

I came to this through trial and error

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [hovered, setHovered] = useState(false);
  const [testInput, setTestInput] = useState("");
  const showLastFourDigits = (value) => {
    if (value.length == 9) {
      const result = "*".repeat(value.length - 4) + value.slice(-4);
      return result;
    } else {
      return value;
    }
  };

  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(testInput);
  };

  return (
    <form className="App">
      <input
        value={!hovered ? showLastFourDigits(testInput) : testInput}
        onChange={(e) => setTestInput(e.target.value)}
        onFocus={() => setHovered(true)}
        onBlur={() => setHovered(false)}
        maxLength={9}
      />
      <button onClick={onSubmit}>Submit</button>
      <p>testInput:{testInput}</p>
    </form>
  );
}
```

[Code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/cool-wave-yj9ddk?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt3q9k170006356hkychqa3a%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt3q9k160002356h2hfvfoj8%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt3q9k160003356hobp765qa%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt3q9k160005356h1yjz2fdc%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clt3q9k160002356h2hfvfoj8%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt3q9k160002356h2hfvfoj8%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%257D%252C%2522clt3q9k160005356h1yjz2fdc%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt3q9k160004356hdan210j8%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A0%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt3q9k160005356h1yjz2fdc%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clt3q9k160004356hdan210j8%2522%257D%252C%2522clt3q9k160003356hobp765qa%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt3q9k160003356hobp765qa%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)

As you could see. If I hover it, it shows the full input. If I unhover it, it becomes *****6789. For reason I'm not sure why but onChange doesn't run if I do it this way. Is this secure? I'm concerned whether if i click onsubmit it might show *****6789 instead of 123456789. Is this the recommended way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I honestly would not recommend messing with the actual value just to achieve a purely visual effect. I did this in the past and ran into several problems, that weren't apparent at first. Some things I recall:

- clicking into the input would not set the caret position correctly in some browsers (because the input value changed the very moment when clicked and thereby invalidating the selection position)
- The modified value would find its way into the further processing chain ending up being sent to the backend
- validation would break because an input that only allows numeric input can't contain asterisks ***1233

And there is a wonderful alternative without the trouble:
Do the switcheroo purely with CSS. Place two different elements into the DOM:

- one is the input which contains the actual value (free from tampering)
- the other is an element that display the masked value (this can be an input with readonly, or a div, or anything that allows you to get the visual effect you are aiming for)
- you use :focus and :hover (and what else you want to include) to control the visibility of the two elements
- css property `pointer-events` allows fine control over which element receives the hover events.

Here is an example, just to illustrate the idea:

```
const maskedValue = maskAllExceptFinal(value)

<div className="container">
  <input className="actual-value" value={value} onChange={...} />
  <input className="masked-display" value={maskedValue} readonly aria-hidden="true" />
</div>
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.container:hover {
  & .masked-display {
    display: none;
  }
}

.actual-value {
  // ...
}

.masked-display {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to mask and unmask in response to two criteria: element [focus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/focus_event) and [hover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover) state… and it appears as though you already figured out the `focus` and `blur` logic. Great!

JS doesn't have a "hover" event, but a close approximation can be implemented using the events [`mouseenter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseenter_event) and [`mouseleave`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseleave_event). The logic for `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` is similar to `focus` and `blur` respectively, except that they should only operate if the element is not focused.

Whether the element has focus can be determined in JS by comparing the element to [`document.activeElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/activeElement). Here's a minimal, reproducible example:

```html
<style>body { font-family: sans-serif; }</style>
<div id="root"></div><script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react@18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script><script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react-dom@18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script><script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@babel/standalone@7.23.10/babel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel" data-type="module" data-presets="env,react">

// This Stack Overflow snippet demo uses UMD modules
const { StrictMode, useState } = React;

function maskAllExceptFinal(str, options = {}) {
  const { maskToken = "*", revealCount = 4 } = options;
  return str.length <= revealCount
    ? str
    : `${maskToken.repeat(str.length - revealCount)}${str.slice(-4)}`;
}

function App() {
  const [masked, setMasked] = useState(true);
  const [testInput, setTestInput] = useState("");

  const handleSubmit = (ev) => {
    ev.preventDefault();
    console.log(testInput);
  };

  const handleMask = (ev) => {
    const isFocused = document.activeElement === ev.currentTarget;
    switch (ev.type) {
      case "blur": {
        setMasked(true);
        break;
      }
      case "focus": {
        setMasked(false);
        break;
      }
      case "mouseenter": {
        if (!isFocused) setMasked(false);
        break;
      }
      case "mouseleave": {
        if (!isFocused) setMasked(true);
        break;
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <form>
      <input
        onBlur={handleMask}
        onChange={(ev) => setTestInput(ev.target.value)}
        onFocus={handleMask}
        onMouseEnter={handleMask}
        onMouseLeave={handleMask}
        maxLength={9}
        value={masked ? maskAllExceptFinal(testInput) : testInput}
      />
      <button onClick={handleSubmit}>Submit</button>
      <p>testInput: {testInput}</p>
    </form>
  );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
  <StrictMode>
    <App />
  </StrictMode>,
);

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is alright as long as you aren't using `<form onSubmit= {function}>` to process the input, in which case the masked value  (*****6789) will passed as the input value.